# Apply Sobel Operator on Point having x,y,z coordinates for segmentaion

Tags: c#, 3d

Using C# how to perform Edge detection using 3D sobel edge operator emphasizes edge details using three 3×3×3 masks, one detecting x-gradients, the second one detects the y gradients and the third one detects the z-gradients.

Comment: Have a look here 
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/2c8218cc-921c-34d8-5c88-39c652488490.htm and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93642/Canny-Edge-Detection-in-C